How do I resolve numpy.core.multiarray failed to import error in gcp cloud function
In GCP cloud functions, this is my requirements.txt file:
Flask>=1.0,<3.0
functions-framework==3.0.0
librosa
soundfile
google-cloud-storage
deeprhythm

When I try to make a post request, I'm hitting this error:

ERROR:root:Error processing audio: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import (auto-generated because you didn't call 'numpy.import_array()' after cimporting numpy; use 'numpy._import_array' to disable if you are certain you don't need it).

I have tried to install lower versions of numpy but when I did that in my requirements.txt file, deployment threw an error - it seems like there's dependency issues with the other packages.
I do not face any errors in my local environment, when I was coding it in google colabs, here's my code here.
How do I resolve this error? Appreciate any help!

Have a look at the suggestions shared in this Link.
